# which is better to promote? IFRAMEs or External Javascripts

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, external

I want to provide a way for bloggers to use my **link list** in their **blogs**.
which type of code should i provide?
**IFRAME or External Javascript ?**

the different aspects i think that are involved are SEO, Browser Compatibility, Cross Platform, Performance, and the code should be allowed in mose Blog Services.

which one do u suggest?

Comment: i hadn't seen that; is it related to StackOverflow?
if so i think that has a conflict in subject with this site

Answer (score 2):

Provide both.

With iFrames your bloggers cannot have their sites validate in XHTML strict. With JavaScript version, they can.

On the other hand, JavaScript content won't be visible for search engines. Whether it's good or bad depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Also give them a PHP include way so that it embeds the content directly into their page.

Comment: how can i do this? consider that the content of the box is dynamic.
do u mean a PHP code that fetch the links remotely from my server?